# How to find min value of another column greater than current column Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate, min

I am sure this is an easy one, but how do I find the minimum value of a column that is greater than the value in the current column?  Also, how do I find the maximum  value of a column less that the value in the current column?

```
from io import StringIO
import io

text = """Order   starttime               endtime
1       2016-03-01 14:31:10.777  2016-03-01 14:31:10.803
1       2016-03-01 14:31:10.779  2016-03-01 14:31:10.780
1       2016-03-01 14:31:10.790  2016-03-01 14:31:10.791
1       2016-03-01 14:31:10.806  2016-03-01 14:31:10.863"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text), sep='\s{2,}', engine='python', parse_dates=[1, 2])
```

So.. example.. 
   for the endtime column, I want the minimum value of the starttime column that is greater to that value.

The value associated with then endtime 2016-03-01 14:31:10.803 (the first value)
would then be  2016-03-01 14:31:10.806 (the last value of startdatetime).

The value associated with 2016-03-01 14:31:10.780 (the second endtime) should then be 2016-03-01 14:31:10.790

So basically (in pseudocode)

df['nexttime'] = min(df['starttime'])>df['endtime']

Would appreciate any help .. I'm sure this is pretty easy for someone more skilled than I am

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
df.endtime.apply(lambda x: min(df.starttime[df.starttime > x]) if len(df.starttime[df.starttime > x]) != 0 else np.nan)

# 0   2016-03-01 14:31:10.806
# 1   2016-03-01 14:31:10.790
# 2   2016-03-01 14:31:10.806
# 3                       NaT
# Name: endtime, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Or slightly more efficient way:

```
def findMin(x):
    larger = df.starttime[df.starttime > x]
    if len(larger) != 0:
        return min(larger)
    else:
        return np.nan

df.endtime.apply(findMin)

# 0   2016-03-01 14:31:10.806
# 1   2016-03-01 14:31:10.790
# 2   2016-03-01 14:31:10.806
# 3                       NaT
# Name: endtime, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

There is probably a way to avoid the vector scan, but if the performance is not a big issue, this works.